# How can I override change_email.html and change_email_and_password.phtml

Tags: magento2, customer, email-templates

I am trying to override the following e-mail templates:

- `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/change_email.html`
- `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/change_email_and_password.html`

I'm trying to do this by copying the templates to my local theme to these paths:

- `app/design/frontend/<PACKAGE>/default/Magento_Customer/templates/email/change_email.html`
- `app/design/frontend/<PACKAGE>/default/Magento_Customer/templates/email/change_email_and_password.html`

However, it does not seem to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction? This is the right way to override e-mail templates right? Or am I overseeing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the templates in

```
app/design/frontend/<PACKAGE>/default/Magento_Customer/email/change_email.html
app/design/frontend/<PACKAGE>/default/Magento_Customer/email/change_email_and_password.html
```

Comment: It's a correct answer.